# Heroku flask app failed: importlib.util module not found Error

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy a flask app with Heroku and I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError`. I don't understand why because all of my modules are up-to-date. Does anybody know how to fix this error?

[image: CMD image]

Here is the code that I am using. The code builds fine, I just can't seem to get the app to deploy correctly.

```
import pickle
from flask import Flask
from flask import request,jsonify,render_template,abort
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import json
import numpy as np
from importlib import util

app = Flask(__name__)

model = pickle.load(open("Final_Gait_Model.sav", "rb"))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def get_info_predict():

    features = []
    result = request.form

    L_Ank_Force_LHS = float(input('Left Ankle Force at LHS (N): '))
    features.append(L_Ank_Force_LHS)

    L_Ank_Moment_Z_LHS = float(input('Left Ankle Moment (Z-axis) at LHS (Nm): '))
    features.append(L_Ank_Moment_Z_LHS)

    L_Knee_Force_LHS = float(input('Left Knee Force at LHS (N): '))
    features.append(L_Knee_Force_LHS)

    L_Ank_Moment_Y_Stance=float(input('Left Ankle Moment (Y-axis) during stance (Nm): '))
    features.append(L_Ank_Moment_Y_Stance)

    L_Knee_Vel_Y_Stance=float(input('Left Knee Angular Velocity (Y-axis) during stance (deg/s): '))
    features.append(L_Knee_Vel_Y_Stance)

    L_Knee_Vel_Z_Stance=float(input('Left Knee Angular Velocity (Z-Axis) during stance (deg/s): '))
    features.append(L_Knee_Vel_Z_Stance)

    R_Ank_Moment_Y_Stance=float(input('Right Ankle Moment (Y-axis) during stance (Nm): '))
    features.append(R_Ank_Moment_Y_Stance)

    R_Knee_Vel_Y_Stance=float(input('Right Knee Angular Velocity (Y-axis) during stance (deg/s): '))
    features.append(R_Knee_Vel_Y_Stance)

    R_Knee_Vel_Z_Stance=float(input('Right Knee Angular Velocity (Z-axis) during stance (deg/s): '))
    features.append(R_Knee_Vel_Z_Stance)

    R_Ank_Force_RHS=float(input('Right Ankle Force at RHS (N): '))
    features.append(R_Ank_Force_RHS)

    R_Ank_Moment_Z_RHS=float(input('Right Ankle Moment (Z-axis) at RHS (Nm): '))
    features.append(R_Ank_Moment_Z_RHS)

    R_Knee_Force_RHS=float(input('Right Kneed Force at RHS (N): '))
    features.append(R_Knee_Force_RHS)

    features = input_to_one_hot(features)

    prediction = model.predict([features])[0]

    return json.dumps({'Injury Classisfication':prediction});


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8080, debug = True)
```

Comment: I'm haven't used importlib yet, but reading your python script, you don't use it in your script. Do you really need it ?

Comment: Yeah I don't use it in my script at all however the module is a requirement to deploy the app for Heroku. It is listed in the requirements.txt file. For some reason it is having trouble finding the module during deployment. I think it may have something to do with sklearn because I get the deprecation warning for importlib when I build the code.